# .Net core constructor DI having more than one service throwing 500 error

Tags: api, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

My project is in .net core 6.0
And the structure is I have one API project with controller which will call the service project (having 2 service classes)

EmployeeService.cs and EmployeeApprovalService.cs are the two services classed.

EmployeeApprovalServiceclass has EmployeeService class injected in constructor and added in Configuration via Scoped DI.

The flow is like MethodA from EmployeeService will call MethodB in EmployeeApprovalService.
Now after business logic MethodB in EmployeeApprovalService might call MethodC in EmployeeService.

SO when I inject EmployeeApprovalService  in constructor of EmployeeService -- everything works fine.
When I inject EmployeeService in the constructor of EmployeeApprovalService  - then when sending the request I am getting 500 response code and no specific error.

Below  are the other details.
Please guide.

```
**In configurationService method :**

  services.TryAddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
  services.TryAddScoped<IEmployeeApprovalService, EmployeeApprovalService>();


**Inside  EmployeService class** 

private readonly IEmployeeApprovalService _empApprovalService;

public EmployeService(IEmployeeApprovalService empApprovalService)
{
_empApprovalService = empApprovalService;
}

// _empApprovalService.MethodB();  method call

**Inside of EmployeeApprovalService**

private readonly IEmployeService _empService;

public EmployeeApprovalService(IEmployeService empService)
{
_empService = empService;
}

_empService.MethodA(); // call to method inside of EMployeeService
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It crashes because you have created a **circular dependency** [(nice article about the topic here)](https://medium.com/software-ascending/circular-dependencies-in-dependency-injection-403b790daebb).

`EmployeeApprovalService` depend on `IEmployeService` and `EmployeeService` depend on `IEmployeeApprovalService`. This makes it impossible to resolve the dependencies, therefore the internal server error.

You need to rethink your design. One option is not to inject `IEmployeeApprovalService` into `EmployeeService` and handle method logic inside of `EmployeeApprovalService`. One can think `EmployeeService` is higher in the graph hierarchy and therefore should be injected into lower, more specific services, as the name of `EmployeeApprovalService` sounds to be.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. 
SO now I am trying a new approach. 
Now I have a 3rd class by the name EmployeeHistory, 
Trying to break the circular dependency , EmployeeApproval is dependent on Employee which is injected in Employee constructor,  
EmployeeHistory has DI on EmployeeApproval class constructor. 

So it is not a circular dependency, even thought that is the case -- still throws 500 error :(